# Scroll behind fixed panel in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a fixed panel heading using Bootstrap and I have content below that panel which should be scrolled behind the panel heading and disappear above the heading.

```
<div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6" style="padding-left: 0;padding-right: 0;position:fixed;z-index:100">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">
    my panel
    </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Initial view:
[image]

When scrolling:
[image]

What I want to achieve: the scrolled content should disappear between the main navbar and the panel heading (thus above the panel).

I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/95972vr9/).

Comment: From the fiddle seems that the panel do what you are saying. Which is your issue ?

Comment: The scrolled text between top navbar (the black one) and the panel should become invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick-n-dirty solution would be to add a bottom border to your nav element that matches the background color:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u8waLfa3/1/)

```
.navbar {
  border-bottom: 48px solid white; //body bkd color
}
```

Comment: @Alexander Zeitler just curious what solution you settled on for this?